# How do I fix this (perl)

Tags: perl

Here's the code; it's in Perl.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
print "I'll show the prime numbers between 2 and u numbers for you.\n";
print "Pls, enter u numbers.";
my $numberer = <STDIN>;
my @nonprime = qw();
my @all = qw();
for (my $i = 3; $i < $numberer; $i++) {
    my $lenght = @all;
    $all[$lenght] = $i;
    for (my $i = 3; $i < $numberer; $i++) {
        if ($numberer <= 3) {
            print "It's none.";
        } else {
            for (my $i = 3; $i < $numberer; $i++) {
                for (my $j = 2; $j < $numberer; $j++) {
                    if ($i == $j) {
                    } elsif ($i % $j == 0) {
                        my $len = @nonprime;
                        $nonprime[$len] = $i;
                    } else {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        my %h;
        @h{@nonprime} = @nonprime;
        print Dumper [grep {!exists $h{$_}} @all];
```

Can you help me by explaining what the problem is? I try to learn perl programming and do some exercise that is "Write your own program to capture all the prime numbers between 2 and a number the user
gives you."

Comment: One simple fix is to remove the Python and C tags — they are not relevant to a question about Perl.  I've done it for you this time.  In future, do not include irrelevant language tags.

Comment: You forgot to describe the problem and for what input it occurs. Please edit your question to add this important missing information.

Comment: I use stackoverflow for the first time, thanks for yours advice.

Comment: Style suggestion: `push @arr, $val` instead of `$arr[$len] = $val`

Comment: Thanks! I already run it without problem now when I change it like you said.

Comment: Your indentation is broken. You have two nested loops using the same iterator `$i`. Also you are missing several right curly brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Might be this code will help you for your question.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

sub testprime
{
      my $m = shift @_;
      my $i = 2;
      while ($i < $m)
      {
        return 0 unless ($m % $i++);
      }
      return 1;
}

print "Enter a number to find the prime \n";
chomp (my $n = <STDIN>);
system 'cls';
for(my $i=2; $i<=$n; $i++)
{
    my $FindPrime = testprime $i;
    if ( $FindPrime == 1)
    {
          print "Yes, the given number - $i is Prime \n";
    }
    else
    {
          print "No, It is NOT a prime Number - $i \n";
    }
}
```

Thnx.